# How to unit test with OpportunityLineItemSchedule objects?

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx

I wrote a OpportunityLineItem trigger that works with the OpportunityLineItemSchedule items related to it. Now I want to write unit tests for this trigger, and want to use sfdx to push the code to a scratch org to test things.

However, `sfdx force:source:push` fails on this (simplified) code:

```
@isTest
private class OpportunityLineItemTest {
    @isTest static void test() {
        OpportunityLineItemSchedule schedule = new OpportunityLineItemSchedule();
    }
}
```

with the error:

```
Invalid type: OpportunityLineItemSchedule
```

How do I create a unit test for OpportunityLineItem objects that use OpportunityLineItemSchedule objects? Do I need to enable a certain feature in the `project-scratch-def.json` to be able to use these objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We plan to deprecate support for org preferences in Winter ’20. [[see here]](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm)

As original answer uses them, and they don't convert 1:1 to `settings`, I am leaving this here for future reference:

```
{
  "orgName": "Demo Company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "country": "US",
  "language": "en_US",
  "features": ["ProductsAndSchedules"],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "productSettings": {
      "enableQuantitySchedule": true,
      "enableRevenueSchedule": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to enable a [Product schedule feature](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) in the `project-scratch-def.json`, e.g. like this:

```
{
  "country": "US",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [],
  "orgPreferences": {
    "enabled": [
      "S1DesktopEnabled",
      "IsRevenueScheduleEnabled"
    ],
    "disabled": []
  },
  "orgName": "My Org",
  "adminEmail": "admin@my.org"
}
```

Once you create the scratch org with `IsRevenueScheduleEnabled` enabled, the type `OpportunityLineItemSchedule` will be available in unit tests.

Comment: My bad, i thought OpportunityLineItemSchedule  is triggername