# Use OpportunityLineItemSchedule custom fields in the unlocked package

Tags: unlocked-package

is it possible to use custom fields from the OpportunityLineItemSchedule object in the unlocked package? We received an error when tried to create a package version

`OpportunityLineItemSchedule: Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix (e.g. __c)`

Comment: Have you checked this perm [Enable customization of product schedules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_features_core_products.htm&release=220&type=5) on Product Schedules Settings?  also I do not see any field with fullName on [OpportunityLineItemSchedule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.ja-jp.212.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitemschedule.htm) and limit of custom field on object is 50.

Comment: @Vinay, the problem is with new package version creation, not with the org setting.

Comment: I did not have an experience working with the `OpportunityLineItemSchedule` in scratch orgs, but I believe this is a feature that needs to be enabled in the Scratch org via org-def.json file (see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239772/how-to-unit-test-with-opportunitylineitemschedule-objects).
And you may need to add the `"definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json"` property to your packageDirectory in the `sfdx-project.json` file, so that it knows that your package uses this feature when packaging.